# Adding Ruby Gems to my PuPHPet provisioner

Tags: rubygems, vagrant, puppet, puphpet

I'm new to Vagrant and Puppet so I'm using the excellent tool provided by PuPHPet (https://puphpet.com/).

I'm putting together a fairly straight forward LAMP box.

Everything is coming along swimmingly except I can't add Ruby Gems. I need to include `sass` and `compass` but I have no idea how and haven't been able to find the answer online anywhere.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the Ruby tab, in the Languages section.

[image: Add as many gems as you want under the "Installed Gems" field.]